# getting infos from my site to another web page

Tags: my-site, my-profile

i'm making a universty portal and all academic staff has their own my site profile. They have also basic personal web page on university page. i want to get some infos from my site to that basic web page. i want to get especially blog part.

is there any way to do this? can this be made?

thank you and good work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain of what you are asking. Is the university page a Sharepoint site in the same farm? In that case you can use e.g. the data view web part to get blogs to display on a central page.

If it's another kind of site (i.e. non SharePoint), I guess Sharepoint web services could help you accomplish this, but there might be easier ways.

Would be nice if you could explain a little more.

Answer (score 0):

thank you i've found the solution ;

i can get their infos from the list / library content using standard SPWeb / SPList / SPListItem methods.